# How to set the precision in numbers

Tags: siunitx

I include the number as `\num{0.12368455}`. I need to print '0.1237'.

**How to do this...**

Answer (score 71, accepted):

With the [the `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) you can use the option `round-mode=places, round-precision=4` to obtain the desired results.

1. If you only need to control the rounding for a few numbers you use it as an option to `\num`:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \begin{document}
   \num{0.12368455}

   \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{0.12368455}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. If you need to do this for the entire document you can use `\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=4}` so that this formatting is applied for the entire document:

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{siunitx}
   \sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=4}

   \begin{document}
      \num{0.12368455}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Another way of achieving this is to use `round-mode=figures, round-precision=4`.

   [image]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{siunitx}

   \begin{document}
       \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=4]{0.12368455}\par
       \num[round-mode=figures,round-precision=4]{0.12}\par
       \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{0.12368455}\par
       \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{0.12}
   \end{document}
   ```

### `round-mode=figures` vs `round-mode=places`

With `[round-mode=figures,round-precision=4]` you get 4 significant figures, and 
with `[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]` you get 4 decimal places. Here is a comparison:

[image]

---

Similar results can also be achieved using `\pgfmathprintnumber`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand*{\MyNum}[1]{%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[
        fixed,
        precision=4,
        fixed zerofill=true,
        ]{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\MyNum{0.12368455}\par
\MyNum{0.12}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @PeterGrill I'd suggest adding another example to the third paragraph to visualize the difference between `figures` and `places`, e.g. `\num[...]{12.12}`.

Comment: @dgs: Have added the requested info.  If it can be improved in any way, please let me know.

Comment: Would you please tell me what option is responsible for printing `0.1234` as `0.123`, while `0.12` should be printed as it is without adding an additional zero?

Comment: @Diaa: I suggest you post a new question for that. If you are having difficulty chances are other will also so would make a good question. In the meantime you can use `\newcommand*{\MyNum}[1]{\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{#1}}`.