# Changing fraction style in LaTeX as generated by Matlab

Tags: tables, fractions, matlab

```
A= [0.7577    0.7060    0.8235    0.4387    0.4898
    0.7431    0.0318    0.6948    0.3816    0.4456
    0.3922    0.2769    0.3171    0.7655    0.6463
    0.6555    0.0462    0.9502    0.7952    0.7094
    0.1712    0.0971    0.0344    0.1869    0.7547]
latex_table = latex(sym(A));
I save it as eqA.
equations1.tex
    \newcommand{\eqA}{
            \left(
                    \begin{array}{ccccc}
                  \frac{6825116339432507}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{6359497797823013}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{3708524368810113}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{987964467329731}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{4411405500742427}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                  \frac{6693542213068579}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{71681197541747}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{6258459855040489}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{859193262592067}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{1003370923741521}{2251799813685248}\\ 
                  \frac{55201045594335}{140737488355328} & 
                  \frac{2494300503760379}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{2856178200482939}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{1723790560926853}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{2910735031501795}{4503599627370496}\\ 
                  \frac{2952009981953243}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{415874915283285}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{8558839330135289}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{3581261978445933}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{6389390375844301}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                  \frac{770956303438939}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{874885307559191}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{77565677658637}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{1683198784473707}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{6797613319514473}{9007199254740992}
              \end{array}
                      \right)
    }

//latex
\documentclass{article}
\input{equations1}

\begin{document}
    Here we have a nice matrix:
    \[
        \eqA{}
    \]

\end{document}
```

I ' m getting right answer but its different format: How can I get original format like A.

[image]

Last but not least, how can I add horizontal and vertical lines and lable colume and rows of the table. The contents of the table should be updated every time by input equation1.

Comment: Please edit your question to make a latex document that we can use locally to reproduce the matrix shown. (eg add the contents of `equation1.tex` to your question)

Comment: @ David Carlisle  done.

Comment: If you don't use `sym()` in Matlab, is the result better?

Comment: I don't have a sym command in matlab (is that the symbolic toolbox)  It is presumably returning a matrix of fractions, if you want a matrix of double as in your original matrx it would be easer to coerce the matrix to double in matlab before converting to latex so (untested) `latex(double(sym(A)))`

Comment: ??? Undefined function or method 'latex' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Is the `latex` function not in the current folder in Matlab or its path? David's suggestion works fine here.

Comment: ??? Undefined function or method 'latex' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in ==> table at 12
latex_table =latex(double(sym(A)))

Comment: Typical error if `latex.m` is not in either the current folder of Matlab, or the path. File --> Set Path, add the folder where you placed `latex.m`. But you've used it before, haven't you? Surely you know what you did to make it work then ..

Comment: what does help latex say in matlab  (I don't have that command either)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assumed it was this one http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2832-latex (Oh, and you're right about `sym` being from the symbolic math toolbox by the way.)

Comment: A=rand(5);

latex_table = latex(sym(A)) % it works
latex_table =latex(double(sym(A))) % error

Comment: @TorbjørnT. so applying sym and coercing to double is probably same as not doing anything?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yep, `latex(double(sym(A)))` gives the same as `latex(A)`.

Comment: @user31177 And if you drop both `sym` and `double`? I.e. `latex(A)`?

Comment: the exanples on the latex function you showed include latex(toeplitz(1:4),'%i','%.2f')  so you can apply a decimal format string so format to as many decimal places as you want. @user31177 _is_ that the `latex` function you are using or is it a differnt one?

Comment: @ i 'm using built in latex function.

Comment: @user31177 Sorry, my mistake. I've never used that toolbox much, and I wasn't aware that it contained that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the matrix to be displayed with decimal values, you could simply redefine the `\frac{}{}` macro to produce the decimal result for you.

All you need to do is to call `\ConverFracToDecimal` and you will get the first result below. Without using `\ConverFracToDecimal` you obtain the second result:

[image]

### Notes:

- [The `fp` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fp) was used for the computation.
- [The `siunitx` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) was used to round and format the decimal digits.  See [How to set the precision in numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/how-to-set-the-precision-in-numbers) for more options.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\ConverFracToDecimal}{%
    \renewcommand*{\frac}[2]{%
        \FPdiv\Result{##1}{##2}%
        \num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{\Result}%
    }%
}%

\newcommand{\eqA}{
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
    \frac{6825116339432507}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{6359497797823013}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{3708524368810113}{4503599627370496} & 
    \frac{987964467329731}{2251799813685248} & 
    \frac{4411405500742427}{9007199254740992}\\ 
    \frac{6693542213068579}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{71681197541747}{2251799813685248} & 
    \frac{6258459855040489}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{859193262592067}{2251799813685248} & 
    \frac{1003370923741521}{2251799813685248}\\ 
    \frac{55201045594335}{140737488355328} & 
    \frac{2494300503760379}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{2856178200482939}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{1723790560926853}{2251799813685248} & 
    \frac{2910735031501795}{4503599627370496}\\ 
    \frac{2952009981953243}{4503599627370496} & 
    \frac{415874915283285}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{8558839330135289}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{3581261978445933}{4503599627370496} & 
    \frac{6389390375844301}{9007199254740992}\\ 
    \frac{770956303438939}{4503599627370496} & 
    \frac{874885307559191}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{77565677658637}{2251799813685248} & 
    \frac{1683198784473707}{9007199254740992} & 
    \frac{6797613319514473}{9007199254740992}
\end{array}
\right)
}

\begin{document} 
$\ConverFracToDecimal\eqA$

\bigskip
Without caling \verb|\ConverFracToDecimal| you get:
\medskip

$\eqA$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The latex output being used is from the symbolic toolbox

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/latex.html

If you use the alternative latex output function mentioned in comments

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2832-latex

then you get

```
>> latex(A,'nomath')
0.75770 & 0.70600 & 0.82350 & 0.43870 & 0.48980 \\
0.74310 & 0.031800 & 0.69480 & 0.38160 & 0.44560 \\
0.39220 & 0.27690 & 0.31710 & 0.76550 & 0.64630 \\
0.65550 & 0.046200 & 0.95020 & 0.79520 & 0.70940 \\
0.17120 & 0.097100 & 0.034400 & 0.18690 & 0.75470
```

and a typeset output of

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix}

    0.75770 & 0.70600 & 0.82350 & 0.43870 & 0.48980 \\
    0.74310 & 0.031800 & 0.69480 & 0.38160 & 0.44560 \\
    0.39220 & 0.27690 & 0.31710 & 0.76550 & 0.64630 \\
    0.65550 & 0.046200 & 0.95020 & 0.79520 & 0.70940 \\
    0.17120 & 0.097100 & 0.034400 & 0.18690 & 0.75470 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe (most of) what you're asking is to increase the spacing between the fractions.

From [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14071/how-can-i-increase-the-line-spacing-in-a-matrix), what you want to do is increase the `\arraystrech`.

This can be done *very* easily, just insert  `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}` right at the start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
    \newcommand{\eqA}{{\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
            \left(
                    \begin{array}{ccccc}
                  \frac{6825116339432507}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{6359497797823013}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{3708524368810113}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{987964467329731}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{4411405500742427}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                  \frac{6693542213068579}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{71681197541747}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{6258459855040489}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{859193262592067}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{1003370923741521}{2251799813685248}\\ 
                  \frac{55201045594335}{140737488355328} & 
                  \frac{2494300503760379}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{2856178200482939}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{1723790560926853}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{2910735031501795}{4503599627370496}\\ 
                  \frac{2952009981953243}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{415874915283285}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{8558839330135289}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{3581261978445933}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{6389390375844301}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                  \frac{770956303438939}{4503599627370496} & 
                  \frac{874885307559191}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{77565677658637}{2251799813685248} & 
                  \frac{1683198784473707}{9007199254740992} & 
                  \frac{6797613319514473}{9007199254740992}
              \end{array}
                      \right)}
    }

\begin{document}
$\eqA$
\end{document}
```

giving

[image: output]

To create lines between the fractions, use an `\hline` after as many `\\` as you like. This gives

[image: output again]

Adding `|` (as in a `tabular` environment, eg `\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}`) produces the vertical lines:

[image: even more output]

---

Evaluating the fractions is a fair bit more complicated, but can be at least accomplished with `pgf`/`tikz`. (I would assume `calc` would work, but I've never worked with it.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\evalfrac}[2]{\pgfmathparse{#1/#2}\pgfmathresult}

\newcommand{\eqA}
{
    \ensuremath
    {
    \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \let\oldfrac\frac             % set up a temporary holder for the normal frac
    \let\frac\evalfrac            % make frac the evalfrac
    \left(
    \begin{array}{c|c}
      \frac{1}{4} & 
      \frac{2}{4}\\ \hline
      \frac{3}{4} &               % do what you do best
      \frac{4}{4}
    \end{array}
    \right)
    \let\frac\oldfrac             % make frac happy again
    }
}

\begin{document}
$\eqA$

Test. Another test fraction $\frac{1}{2}$.
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: moar]

This unfortunately does not work with larger numbers, but the concept is sound and potentially useful. If you'd like to keep some sanity in your life, I'd go with Peter's answer for the calculation bits.

Comment: Unfortunately, OP wants to get the decimal point numbers instead of fractions.

Comment: `pmatrix` is better than `\left(\begin{array}...\end{array}\right)`; I'd also add a pair of braces around the whole thing, in order to make the change to `\arraystretch` local.

Comment: @percusse, whoops. Not a big matlab guy - mathematica all the way ;) The question can definitely be made more clear as to what the OP wants - I thought he wanted a LaTeX way to do it. (Still researching that btw - `calc` package?

Comment: Don't bother. It's matlab after all it will try to break down all the beauty. :)

Comment: but matlab!! ew!! At least with latex you can throw it in a common preamble and forget about it. With matlab, you have to keep opening it up.

Comment: And witness the horror. I'd also like to see if it can be done. :P

Comment: Oh it can be done but you have to first strip off the numbers and that requires locally in a group overriding `frac` macro to give you the number themselves then since they are integers you can perform the division with `calc`, `pgfmath` etc. ... Oops Peter already did it.

Comment: I hate everything. XD Well at least I learned something :D

Comment: If you turn on the `fpu` library it can handle big numbers too. But it needs more care :)