# Datatool control precision

Tags: datatool

How can I bring down the number of decimal points in following code to only 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
  Name, Age, stDev
  Adam, 17.2344, 3.23333
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata2}{test2.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \bfseries Name & \bfseries Age%
  \DTLforeach{mydata2}{\Name=Name,\Age=Age,\stDev=stDev}%
    {%
    \\\Name & $\Age\pm\stDev$
    }%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps this answers your question: [How to set the precision in numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/how-to-set-the-precision-in-numbers).  Alternatively you could also use the number formatting macros from [the `pgf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) : `\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) already loads [`fp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fp) which provides `\FPround{<out>}{<in>}{<num>}`, rounding `<in>` to `<num>` decimal places and stores it in `<out>`. `datatool` mirrors this with `\DTLround` (and/or `\DTLtrunc` if you wish to truncate rather than round):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{datatool,filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.csv}
Name, Age, stDev
Adam, 17.2344, 3.23333
Eve, 17.56789, 3.95445
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{mydata2}{test2.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\bfseries Name & \bfseries Age%
\DTLforeach{mydata2}{\Name=Name,\Age=Age,\stDev=stDev}%
{%
\\ \Name & \DTLround{\Age}{\Age}{2}\DTLround{\stDev}{\stDev}{2}$\Age\pm\stDev$
}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

See p 30 (under section **3 Fixed Point Arithmetic**) of the [`datatool` user guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf).