# Truncating floating point numbers for display while maintaining full accuracy for computations

Tags: siunitx, expl3

The MWE below suggests that truncating an `fp` type number is not just for cosmetics but actually changes the number's value. Is there a way to reduce the number of decimals displayed without affecting the number's full accuracy in computations? I browsed through `siunitx` but nothing jumped at me.

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 6 April 2017
% TOPIC:
%  Truncating floating point numbers 
%=======================
\usepackage[check-declarations]{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
%-----------------------
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\myTruncatingFloatingPoints{mO{3.11998}O{3.0198}}
  {
    \fp_eval:n {trunc(#2,#1)*trunc(#3,#1)}
  }  %  \myTruncatingFloatingPoints

\ExplSyntaxOff
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
    1. Full complement of digits:~\myTruncatingFloatingPoints{5}

    2. Truncated to 2 decimal digits:~  \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not use a second variable? Assign the value of the first to the second and truncate that one for printing. This way you can calculate with the first one with full accuracy. (might be an ugly workaround)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [How to set the precision in numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59006) (there are more versions, have a look):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{0.12368455}

\num[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]{0.12368455}
\end{document}
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 5):

Here I use `\num` just for pretty printing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,xfp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
No truncation  & \num{\fpeval{3.11998*3.0198}} \\
Truncation     & \num{\fpeval{trunc(3.11998*3.0198,2)}} \\
Bad truncation & \num{\fpeval{trunc(3.11998,2)*trunc(3.0198,2)}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Truncating the result only is the obvious thing to do, except that I wanted truncated versions of the operands, say for instance as elements of a matrix, then do operations with full accuracy ... Anyway, we have had answers.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth I'm afraid I don't understand; computations are distinct from printing the result.

Comment: You are quite right! It seems I got myself into a muddle here.

Answer (score 4):

Because I felt like reinventing the wheel...(again)

EDITED so that truncating to 0 places does not present the decimal.

RE-EDITED to handle negative numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{digits}
\newcommand\myTruncatingFloatingPoints[2]{%
  \whole{#1}#2..\relax%
}
\def\whole#1#2.#3.#4\relax{%
    \presentwhole#2\relax\relax%
    \ifx\relax#3\relax.\trunc{#1}00\relax\else%
      \ifnum#1>0\relax.\trunc{#1}#3\relax\fi%
    \fi%
}
\def\presentwhole#1#2\relax{%
  \ifx-#1\ensuremath{-}\the\numexpr0#2\else\the\numexpr0#1#2\fi%
}
\def\trunc#1#2#3#4\relax{%
  \setcounter{digits}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{digits}{-1}%
  \ifnum\thedigits>0\relax%
    #2%
    \trunc{\thedigits}#3#40\relax%
  \else%
    \ifnum#3<5\relax#2\else\the\numexpr#2+1\relax\fi% ROUNDED
%    #2% TRUNCATED
  \fi%%  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
1. \makebox[.8in][r]{9.421715604} to 5 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{5}{9.421715604}

2. \makebox[.8in][r]{9.421715604} to 3 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{3}{9.421715604}

3. \makebox[.8in][r]{9.421715604} to 1 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{1}{9.421715604}

4. \makebox[.8in][r]{9.421715604} to 0 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{0}{9.421715604}

5. \makebox[.8in][r]{29} to 2 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{2}{29}

6. \makebox[.8in][r]{.1275} to 3 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{3}{.1275}

7. \makebox[.8in][r]{.1275} to 4 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{4}{.1275}

8. \makebox[.8in][r]{$-$.12} to 6 digits: \myTruncatingFloatingPoints{6}{-.12}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Truncated to 0 shouldn't have the decimal point.

Comment: @Tim Done, per your suggestion.