# xfp: zerofill at fpeval

Tags: xfp

I need some calculations with `fpeval`, where I want numbers like '21' outwritten as '21.0' with one zero after the point.

Is this possible at xfp.sty?

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp}
\begin{document}
good: \fpeval{round(1.234,2)}

good too: \fpeval{round(2.34,2)}

not good: \fpeval{round(21,2)}; wanted: 21.0  (with \emph{one} (1) zero in that integer case)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat related [siunitx - Truncating floating point numbers for display while maintaining full accuracy for computations - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362418/truncating-floating-point-numbers-for-display-while-maintaining-full-accuracy-fo)

Answer (score 4):

xfp is for calculations. For pretty printing the numbers use siunitx:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt, varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{xfp,siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[minimum-decimal-digits=1]{\fpeval{round(21,2)}}; 
wanted: 21.0  (with \emph{one} (1) zero in that integer case)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Strange: yields "! Package siunitx Error: Unknown option 'minimum-decimal-digits'."

Comment: then you have an older siunitx. Check its docu how the option was named there.

Comment: Looks like `round-minimum`, `round-mode` (can take value  (off, figures, places)) and `round-precision`. ([documentation for version 2.7n](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf?revision=47489&view=co), [other versions](https://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/doc/latex/siunitx/siunitx.pdf?view=log&log_pagestart=25)